# How to get the id of the checkbox in ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I am new to ember.js and I need to get the id of the checked checkbox in ember.

I have used javascript but in ember it's different.

```
{{input id = 1 type="checkbox"}}
{{input id = 2 type="checkbox"}}
```

If I select the second checkbox I need only the id which is 2.
Can anyone help me out in this ?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define `change` action on your `input` :

```
{{input id = 1 type="checkbox" change=(action "checkboxAction")}}
{{input id = 2 type="checkbox" change=(action "checkboxAction")}}
```

and you can do whatever you want in your action in your component or controller with action param `e`:

```
actions: {
    checkboxAction(e){
      if(e.target.checked){
            this.set("selectedTargetId", e.target.id);
      }
    }
}
```

You can check if target is checked by `e.target.checked` and you can retrieve target id by `e.target.id`.
You can take a look at [this twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/2f7c389a67f099ffa1537ed10cc27fd3) for this usage.